# How to override background color for disabled JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, nimbus

In Java Swing application, I am using nimbus look and feel.
I try to override JPanel background color (enabled or disabled) without success.

[Doc oracle, Nimbus Defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary) -> Search "Panel.background".

I instantiate the JPanel like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void updateUI() {

            if ("Nimbus".equals(UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getName())) {
                UIDefaults map = new UIDefaults();
                map.put("Panel.background", Color.yellow); // Works fine :)
                map.put("Panel.disabled", Color.red); // Don't work :'(
                putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", map);
            }
            super.updateUI();
        }
    };
```

I am trying too:

```
map.put("Panel[Disabled].background", Color.blue); // Don't work too :'(
```

Comment: maybe try the `Panel[Disabled].backgroundPainter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have found my mistake.

```
map.put("Panel.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.yellow));
map.put("Panel[Disabled].background", new ColorUIResource(Color.red));
```

Missing "new ColorUIResource".
This works like a charm.